# Can I use Google Analytics to count QuickTime installations?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

By default, Google Analytics produces reports on which versions of Flash and Java my users have.  Is it possible to set up a report on which versions of QuickTime (if any)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to track which version of Quicktime a user has installed using Google Analytics out of the box.

However, you should be able to detect which version of QT is running using JavaScript, and then set it as a Custom Variable.  Here is some old code from Apple for version detection:

http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/detectplugins.html

Google Analytics Custom Variables:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html