# Does Google Analytics allow custom variables to have a value of zero?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

I was interested in tracking the versions of QuickTime my users have installed.  As suggested in an [earlier question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13405/can-i-use-google-analytics-to-count-quicktime-installations), I have set up a custom variable and built a report around it. Here is my code for the check:

```
function qt_check(){
    var p = navigator.plugins;
    var name, ver = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
        name = p[i].name;
        if(name.indexOf("QuickTime Plug-in") !== -1){ ver = p[i].version; }
    }
    return ver;
}
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "QuickTime Version", qt_check(), 1);
```

As you can see, I set up the `qt_check()` function so that it would return a value of zero if the user does not have any version of QuickTime installed.  My idea was that in addition to getting a readout on the various versions of QuickTime, I would be able to see how many people don't have it at all by looking for version "0".

But now that I have a few days of data, I find that although there have been 933 visits during that time, nobody registered as having QuickTime version 0.

Should I be passing some other value to Google Analytics?  Is the 0 causing it to discard the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `0` is a falsy value in JavaScript. So, any number EXCEPT zero will just be cast to a string if you pass it as a Number. But, since `0` evaluates as false, it gets interpreted that you're not passing a value for a required field, and the `setCustomVar` fails. So, yes, setting it to `"0"` instead of `0` will work.

Answer (score 3):

The `_setCustomVar` function takes a string for a value and you're setting ver to a number 0. I think you need to set it to `"0"`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try and report back once there's been time for the data to hit Google Analytics.

Comment: @Will Martin you can use Google Analytics Debug to test it out manually. I did so, and setting it to "0" instead of 0 works, though for non-zero numbers, it'll cast them to a string without trouble. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: @yc01 Good tip, +1.  I tried it out with "none" as the default value, and it works fine. Thanks to you and @paulmorriss.